# Calculating and identifying maximum distance between points using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, distance

I have these 12 sites mapped on ArcGIS Pro. I am trying to set up an experiment that has 4 treatments. Since I have 12 sites I was hoping to allocate 3 sites per treatment so 3 replicates per treatment.

I want each replicate per treatment to be as far as possible from one another.

Is it possible to calculate this using ArcGIS Pro?

To clarify I am trying to say: Treatment 1 has 3 replicates. From the total of 12 points calculate the three points furthest from each other. For Treatment 2 use the remaining 9 points to calculate the three points furthest from each other and so forth.

[image]

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include statements of appreciation in your posts.

Comment: You had a tag for Spatial Analyst but made no mention of using that extension on your question body so I've removed it.

Comment: "Is it possible" usually have an answer of "Of course." Since you really are looking for "How is it possible"" I suggest you focus the Question on that. Note that 12 sites only have so many combinations, but with larger pools of possibility, this is likely to become a NP task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a deprecated tool named [Point Distance (Analysis)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/point-distance.htm) which:

> Determines the distances from input point features to all points in
> the near features within a specified search radius.

Even if you wanted to use that it required an Advance level license.

Fortunately:

> This functionality has been replaced by [Near](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/near.htm) and [Generate Near
> Table](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/generate-near-table.htm) tools that now calculate distances between point, polyline
> and polygon features.

The [Near](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/near.htm) tool, which is available at all license levels:

> Calculates distance and additional proximity information between the
> input features and the closest feature in another layer or feature
> class.

and the [Generate Near Table](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/generate-near-table.htm) tool, which is also available at all license levels:

> Calculates distances and other proximity information between features
> in one or more feature class or layer. Unlike the Near tool, which
> modifies the input, Generate Near Table writes results to a new
> stand-alone table and supports finding more than one near feature.

I think it is the Generate Near Table tool that you should use as the basis of a solution to what you are trying to do.